# Настройка z-index

Tags: css

Возможно как-то `div2` сделать поверх `div3` без изменения структуры коды?

```css
.div1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}
.div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 20;
}
.div3 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 15;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
div3.before(div2)
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
}
#div3 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```